# What determines whether an action potential is inhibitory or excitatory?

Tags: neuroscience, biophysics, neurophysiology

What determines whether an action potential is inhibitory or excitatory? Is it determined by the receptors, the neurotransmitters, or some other mechanism?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**
The physiological state of the postsynaptic cell ultimately determines the effect of an incoming action potential.

**Background**
An action potential occurring in a chemical synapse is neither inhibitory or excitatory. An action potential is a binary '1', an-all-or-nothing signal without any information, i.e., there is not a -1 or +1 action potential. Similarly, there are no excitatory or inhibitory neurotransmitters.

Notably, the principal excitatory neurotransmitter in the nervous system, glutamate, can have inhibitory effects dependent on the receptor activated. While most metabotropic glutamate receptors (mGluRs) and ionotropic AMPA and NMDA receptors are indeed all excitatory, the inhibitory glutamate receptors (iGluRs) are not [(Cleland, 1996)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8938647).

Conversely, GABA, the principal inhibitory neurotransmitter in the nervous system, can have excitatory postsynaptic effects. For example, hyperpolarized neurons may actually depolarize upon GABA<sub>A</sub> receptor activation, simply because the resting membrane potential is more negative than the reversal potential of Cl<sup>-</sup> (i.e., Cl<sup>-</sup> flows *out* of the cell due to the negative membrane potential) [(Marty & Liano, 2005)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15927683).

The existence of both excitatory and inhibitory glutamate receptors shows that it is the **postsynaptic receptor** that determines whether an action potential will inhibit or excite the postsynaptic neuron. The excitatory effect of GABA<sub>A</sub> activation shows that on top of that, even principal inhibitory neurotransmitters (GABA) with principal inhibitory receptors (GABA<sub>A</sub>) can excite a neuron dependent on its **physiological state**.

Besides chemical synapses there are electrical synapses. In these synapses action potentials are transmitted directly electrically through gap junctions. In this case, *any action potential* is excitatory as the signal will be carried forward if it is strong enough [(Purves e*t al*., 2001)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK11164/).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Cleland, *Mol Neurobiol* (1996); **13**(2): 97-136](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8938647)

**-** [Marty & Liano, *Trends Neurosci* (2005); **28**(6): 284-9](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15927683)

**-** [Purves *et al*., Neuroscience, 2<sup>nd</sup> ed. Sunderland (MA): Sinauer Associates; 2001.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK11164/)</sub>

Comment: After reading your answer, my impression is my question is a bit nonsensical. Does it seem that way to you? I can't tell if I asked a meaningless question or the answer is "it depends and without further info that can't be specified." Thanks for replying btw.

Comment: I think your question makes a lot of sense, because too many people talk about excitatory neurotransmitters and the likes. There *are no inhibitory or excitatory neurotransmitters*. +1 for the question.

Comment: @AliceD, I'd vote for peppering in a few judicious "strictly speaking"s to your answer, since I'd bet most working neuroscientists would give a minor eye roll to your italicized comment point.

Comment: @Chelonian - I'm a working neuroscientist. Which comment are you addressing?

Comment: @Chelonian - and given the nature of the question I don't think any eye roll would be rather misplaced.

Comment: @AliceD I was addressing "There *are no inhibitory or excitatory neurotransmitters*." in your comment to Stan Shunpike, but it also applies to "Similarly, there are no excitatory or inhibitory neurotransmitters." in the answer you gave. I wasn't quite sure what you meant by the 2nd comment to me; do you mean you do think they would be misplaced? I think you're *right*, just that maybe putting "strictly speaking," in these sentences (or something like that) may be helpful, since there are thousands of pieces of legitimate text that refer to "excitatory neurotransmitters", etc.

Comment: The state of the postsynaptic cell does NOT always determine the outcome of an action potential. You seem to be neglecting the whole presynaptic and autoreceptor literature in your answer. The neurotransmitter released doesn't even have to reach the postsynaptic side, it can lower or increase the probability of release in the presynaptic cell for example so your answer needs to be toned down.                                                                                                               c.f Tzingounis, A. V. & Nicoll, R. A. Nat Neurosci 7, 419–420 (2004).

Comment: @V_ix in the light of the question, the answer is valid. Further,  autoreceptors by no means change the effect of an action potential, only subsequent ones. The fact whether neurotransmitter reaches the postsynaptic neuron, in the light of the basic nature of the question that's a bit of an overkill detail. I'd rather not tone down anything and I think you are overinterpreting the question.

Comment: @AliceD I have a related question: You say that NTs are not per se inhibitory or excitatory, but neurons themselves are typically classified as one of the two. How is this possible, given that say the NT released by an inhibitory neuron can also have excitatory effects (depending on the receptor it binds to)?